# Select the latest message thread values from a table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table

```
Id         |   ReceiverId  |   SenderId   | Text
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
1          |   5           |   1          | text
2          |   5           |   1          | text
3          |   1           |   5          | text
4          |   2           |   5          | text
5          |   2           |   5          | text
6          |   5           |   3          | text
7          |   5           |   4          | text
9          |   5           |   6          | text
10         |   5           |   4          | text
11         |   10          |   5          | text
12         |   5           |   10         | text
13         |   10          |   5          | text
14         |   5           |   10         | text
```

How do I select a row with out duplication based on [ReceiverId, SenderId] pair and **Ordered by Id** in **Descending** order. That is: [5, 1]=[1,5] are duplicate. OR [5,1] = [5,1] are also the duplicate.

So the final result should be:

```
Id         |   ReceiverId  |   SenderId   | Text
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
14         |   5           |   10         | text
10         |   5           |   4          | text
9          |   5           |   6          | text
6          |   5           |   3          | text
5          |   2           |   5          | text
3          |   1           |   5          | text
```

Comment: The first two rows have the same `SenderId, ReceiverId` combination, but different `Text`. Which row do you want to show?

Comment: I guess I see what you want, the row with the larger Id, right?

Comment: They should be **ordered by** **Id** first in **Desc**, the one on the bottom of the result will be ignored.

Comment: In your result table the first row has Id = 8, but in your original table there's no row having Id = 8.

Comment: @A2H ya you are right, checkout the edited one

Comment: why not copy your example data over instead of using an image?

Comment: I don't quite get the logic: from the lines with Id (1,2,3) you are choosing the one with Id=3. But from the lines with Id (11,12,13,14) you are choosing the one with Id = 13. I thought you need the one with the largest ID.

Comment: @A2H sorry it was typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that among records, which you consider to be the same by just checking the `SenderId` and `ReceiverId` (order doesn't matter), you want the one with the largest `Id` (which could probably be the latest). Then, this query will give you the result:

```
select Id, ReceiverId, SenderId, [Text]
from MyTable t
where t.Id in (
    select top 1 tt.Id
    from MyTable tt
    where (tt.SenderId = t.SenderId and tt.ReceiverId = t.ReceiverId) or
         (tt.SenderId = t.ReceiverId and tt.ReceiverId = t.SenderId)
    order by tt.Id desc
)
order by t.Id desc
```

**Replace `MyTable` with your table's name.**

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.ID,   
       a.senderid_final,
       a.receiverid_final,
       b.Text 
from 
(
  select a.receiverid as a_receiverid, 
         a.senderid as a_senderid , 
         b.receiverid as b_receiverid, 
         b.senderid as b_senderid, 
         case when max(a.id) > max (b.id) then a.receiverid else b.receiverid end as receiverid_final,
         case when max(a.id) > max (b.id) then a.senderid else b.senderid end as senderid_final
        from my_tables as a
        inner join my_table as b
        on a.receiverid = b.senderid
        and b.receiverid =  a.senderid
        group by a.receiverid, a.senderid, b.receiverid, b.senderid
   ) as a 
   inner join my_tables as b
   on a.receiverid_final = b.receiverid 
   and b.senderid =  a.senderid_final
   Order by b.id desc
```

Comment: **The column 'receiverid' was specified multiple times for 'a'.** error occured. I tried to fix most of the error except for this.

Comment: It should work now, had to rename columns in the sub-query